# Gradient with a change of variables?

Tags: vector-analysis, substitution

Given $w\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ and $f(w) = \frac{1}{2}||y-Xw||^2_2$. My other function is $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(z) = \frac{1}{2}||y-z||^2_2$, the gradients are,

\begin{align}
\nabla_w f(w) &= X^T(Xw-y)\\
\nabla_zg(z) &= z-y.
\end{align}
What happens when I evaluate the gradient of $g(z)$ at $z=Xw$?

**Solution**

My though is that because $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the gradient should produce a value in $\mathbb{R}^n$, meaning,
\begin{align}
\left. \nabla_zg(z)\right|_{z=Xw} = Xw-y.
\end{align}

But my confusion comes from, if I evaluate, $\nabla_wg(Xw)$, then I get,
\begin{align*}
\left. \nabla_zg(z)\right|_{z=Xw} = \nabla_wg(Xw) = X^T(Xw-y).
\end{align*}
But now this value, $X^T(Xw-y)\in\mathbb{R}^d$, which makes me think its wrong. But I am not exactly sure how to approache this substitution of variables.

Comment: The derivative wrt $z$ should result in a vector of the same dimension as $z$ not $w$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\nabla_zg$ to write the differential of the function
$$dg = (z-y) \cdot dz$$
Now use the relationship $\,z=Xw\,$ to switch the independent variable from $z\to w$
$$\eqalign{
dg &= (Xw-y) \cdot (X\,dw) \\
   &= \big(X^T(Xw-y)\big) \cdot dw \\
}$$
and recover the gradient from that last equation
$$\eqalign{
\nabla_wg  &= X^T(Xw-y) \\
}$$
This is identical to the other gradient calculation using
$$f(w) = g(Xw)$$